# Adding WP7 ContextMenu programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu, silverlight-toolkit

I'm loading elements on a page dynamically (reading the contents of an XML file). The dynamic content is loaded into a `StackPanel`. Each element of the content consists of a `TextBlock` and one other UI element, so for each pair I create a new `StackPanel` which is then added to the parent `StackPanel`. The code looks like this:

```
TextBlock header = new TextBlock() {
        Text = "Heading 1",
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"],
      };
TextBox item = new TextBox() {
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
      };
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Children.Add( header );
sp.Children.Add( item );

parentSP.Children.Add( sp );
```

I want to add a `ContextMenu` to this `StackPanel` (`sp`, not `parentSP`); depending on some parameters read from the file it could be one of 2 different context menus. I tried the following but it is not working:

```
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    RoutedEventHandler clickHandler = new RoutedEventHandler( OnContextMenuClicked );

    // Add "edit" entry
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem() {
      Header = "edit",
      Tag = "edit",
    };

    menuItem.Click += clickHandler;
    cm.Items.Add( menuItem );

    // Add "delete" entry
    menuItem = new MenuItem() {
      Header = "delete",
      Tag = "delete",
    };

    menuItem.Click += clickHandler;
    cm.Items.Add( menuItem );

    parentSP.Children.Add( cm );
```

How do I add a context menu to the `StackPanel` programmatically?

Also, is there a better way to solve this problem? Maybe by storing the 2 different types of context menus in a XAML resources section and adding them as needed? I tried doing this by adding the context menus to the parent's `StackPanel.Resource` section but got an error saying "A property element cannot be the direct child of another property element"

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(sp, cm);
```