# Adding a silverlight toolkit for windows phone context menu to a listboxitem in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a set of ListBoxItems which I add dynamically to a StackPanel when my application loads using C# and I am trying to give each of these context menus using the Silverlight toolkit for Windows Phone and I was wondering how could I do this?

I can't find anyway to access the toolkit in C# so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Likely similar to this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543654/adding-wp7-contextmenu-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

[there](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API) is what you want.

You can download latest edtion tookit in that website.